# MySQL query help - exclusively return users with new items only

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I pull a list of users who only have new items?

I tried this query . . .  SELECT * FROM items where status = 'new' GROUP BY item_owner;
but mike shows up  in the output cause he has a new car also, but I only want users with exclusively new cars.

```
Table 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Table: User_Profiles
Id            username
1              mike
2              jim


Table 2
------------------------------------------------------------
Table: Items
Id            item       status    item_owner       
1              car          new       mike
2              car          old       mike
3              car          new       jim
4              car          new       jim
```

I tried this query . . .  SELECT * FROM items where status = 'new' GROUP BY item_owner;
but mike show mike is in the output cause he has a new car also, but I only want users with exclusively new cars.

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM my_table x JOIN y ON y.id = x.id AND y.status = 'old' WHERE y.id IS NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way: count both old and new, then include anyone with (a) one or more `new` and (b) zero `old`:

```
SELECT item_owner
FROM Items
GROUP BY item_owner
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'new' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'old' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/038e7/4

The key is to exclude all owners who have any status other than 'new'

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.item_owner 
FROM items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from items i2 
                  where i2.item_owner = i.item_owner 
                  and i2.status <> 'new')
```

Comment: Please edit to change your subquery to use something like `SELECT 1` - seeing `SELECT *` used like that makes my eyes bleed. Why in the world would you return every column just to see if a row exists?

Comment: This worked also worked great i edited a little SELECT DISTINCT item_owner

Comment: Fair point Ken. I would never use `select *` in a realy query and should not use it in examples here. Edited to reflect this.